# How to solve this problem of finding the Arch support?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am self-studying precalculus on my own. This is a problem from Ron Larson's precalculus 10e

> The arch support of a bridge is 
>   modeled by
>    $y = −0.0012x^2+ 
> 300$, where x and y are 
>   measured in feet and the x-axis represents the ground.
>
> (a) Use a graphing utility to graph the equation.
>
> (b) Find one x-intercept of the graph. Explain how to 
>   use the intercept and the symmetry of the graph to 
>   find the width of the arch support.

For the first question (a) I graphed it on desmos

And for the second problem my approach was to use the distance formula and the answer was 1000feet. Since I am doing everything all on my own I have no way of knowing if my answer is correct or not.

Can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Here is an example of how I would solve the problem.

We begin by finding the $x$-intercepts, using the fact that the $x$-intercepts are the points where $y = 0$
\begin{align}
-0.0012x^2 + 300 = y &= 0 \\
0.0012x^2 &= 300 \\
x^2 = \frac{300}{0.0012} &= 250000
\end{align}
One solution to this equation is $x = \sqrt{250000} = 500$, and since we can see that the graph is symmetric around the $y$-axis, we must have that $x = -\sqrt{250000} = -500$ is also a solution. So we get the width of the arch support to be the difference $500 - (-500) = 1000$ feet between these two points, just as you got.